# Read values of Data Grid in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I need to read all values of a column in a Data Grid in  a WPF Application.

```
for (int i = 0; i < dgridList.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)dgridList.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i);

                TextBlock t_name = dgridList.Columns[0].GetCellContent(row) as TextBlock;
                TextBlock t_type = dgridList.Columns[1].GetCellContent(row) as TextBlock;
                Tuple<string, string> mod = new Tuple<string, string>(t_name.Text, t_type.Text);
                Alist.Add(mod);
            }
```

This is the XMAL declaration of datagrid

```
<DataGrid x:Name ="dgridList" Margin="0,0,0,0" Grid.Row="1" IsReadOnly="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
```

This iteration working properly if data grid contains 3,4 items only (if we add more items in data grid iteration  doesn't work.) .If we increase items , stroller bar also visible. (because data grid size is set to small )

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll

Additional information: Value cannot be null.
```

If I try to read values in data grid (more than 4 items) I'm getting this error.

How can I resolve this.

Comment: Do yourself a favor and learn MVVM. This and other "problems" aren't problems anymore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have set the `ItemsSource` property of the `DataGrid` to an `IEnumerable<YourClass>`, you could just iterate through all `YourClass` objects and get their property values:

```
foreach (var item in dgridList.Items.OfType<YourClass>())
{
    var name = item.t_name;
    var type = item.t_type;
    Tuple<string, string> mod = new Tuple<string, string>(name, type);
    Alist.Add(mod);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**XAML**

```
<DataGrid  ColumnWidth="*" 
       IsReadOnly="True"
       AutoGenerateColumns="False"
       SelectionMode="Single" 
       HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
       VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
       ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
       ItemsSource="{Binding MyData}"
       SelectedItem="{Binding Item}"
 >
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Nº." Binding="{Binding NumberProperty}" MinWidth="100" With="Auto"/>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding NameProperty}" Width="*"/>
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

**ViewModel**  (first it's required implementation of `INotifyPropertyChanged`)

```
private ObservableCollection<MyData> _myData;
private MyData _selectdItem;

public ObservableCollection<MyData> DataCollection 
{
    get { return _myData; }
    set { _myData = value; OnPropertyChanged("DataCollection"); }
}
//Your current selected item in the datagrid
public MyData Item
{
    get { return _selectdItem; }
    set
    {
        _selectdItem = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Item");
    }
}
private void ReadAllItems()
{
    foreach (var item in DataCollection)
    {
        var mod = new Tuple<string, string>(item.Number, item.Name);
        Alist.Add(mod);
    }
}
private void LoadDataCollection()
{
    using (var db = new YourContext())
    {
        //Your DataGrid will fill here
        DataCollection = new ObservableCollection<MyData> ( db.YourEntity.List() )
    }
}
```